# Closest pairs of points with conquer without divide approach

Tags: computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

In an algorithm where I have to search for the pair of points in a plain, with the smallest distance: suppose that we want to use a "Divide and Conquer" approach. Is it possible to make it working by just sorting the points by X coordinates at first and Y coordinates after and get the min distances for all subsequent points.
By choosing this approach what should be chosen as a split and how to refine our closest search ?

Comment: But why? Hmmmm?

Comment: What is "conquer without divide approach"?

Comment: My question was: Is it possible to just divide the points in X pairs and Y pairs and calculate their distances instead of separating them by an imaginary line ?

Comment: Suppose you have found a pair of points with closest X-coordinates and a pair of points with closest Y-coordinates - what will do if these pairs are different?

Comment: I think your question is not very clear. Is your input a set of pairs $\{(x,y)\}^n? and you need to find the pair $(x_i,y_i)$ s.t their distance is minimum?

Comment: Exactly! I was trying to find a different approach to the divide-and-conquer one used in the books. I mean if I sorted by X and I sorted by Y .. I have 2 sets and I kind of already divided the points in 2 sets . So was wondering if given the 2 sorted pair sets I can still calculate the desired result in O (n log n), since I technically know that the final result must reside between the pairs which have close enough X or close enough Y.

Comment: Consider a point set $\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\}$. You'll find two pairs of points - $\{(0,1),(0,-1)\}$ and $\{(1,0),(-1,0)\}$. How will it help you to find a pair of points with minimal distance between them?